# Conditionally rendering Radio Buttons in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, radio-button, conditional-rendering

I am building a React app with a hefty search functionality. Essentially, I need to conditionally render Radio buttons based on other Radio buttons input. I am using the MUI library for Radio buttons.

Here's an example of the type of functionality that I need

```
if (value === 'Option1') {
  return <Option1Radios />
}
```

I know this has to do with useState, so the actual code will look nothing like the above example, but that's the best way I can explain what I'm looking for.

Currently, I have the basic set of radio options that are necessary for all searches at the top. When the user reaches the 3rd set of radio buttons, I need to take their choice in those radio buttons, and render a large selection of radio buttons based upon that 3rd selection. My current plan is to create components for each set of radio buttons that can appear, and then set it up to render those components when the proper button is checked (Option1Radio component, Option2Radio component, etc.)

Example.js

```
                 <Form.Row>
                    <FormControl>
                        <FormLabel id="demo-row-radio-buttons-group-label">Options</FormLabel>
                        <RadioGroup
                            row
                            aria-labelledby="demo-row-radio-buttons-group-label"
                            name="row-radio-buttons-group"
                        >
                            <FormControlLabel value="Option1" control={<Radio />} label="Option1" />
                            <FormControlLabel value="Option2" control={<Radio />} label="Option2" />
                            <FormControlLabel value="Option3" control={<Radio />} label="Option3" />
                        </RadioGroup>
                    </FormControl>
                </Form.Row>
```

I have been looking for a resource on how to conditionally render Radio buttons in this way, but I've been unable to find anything. I would imagine there is some resource that shows me the proper way to set these up, so ideally if someone could link me to that (or even just a website that has implemented this type of searching that I could inspect,) that would be very helpful. If not, if someone could possibly give a code example on how to get this done I would greatly appreciate it.

My assumption on how this needs to be done:

I assume that in my main search page, I need to set the state of the search form.

I assume that I need to change the state of the search form to reflect the value of the specific radio option, so that it will render the appropriate set of options.

Thank you for the help and I'm happy to provide anything else that may help. I know this may seem like a ridiculous question, essentially asking for documentation/guide, but I have searched for a few hours now to no avail! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

You can do conditional rendering like this:

Define the state to control the rendering:

```
const [contition, setCondition] = useState(false);
```

This code only displays `<Option1Radios />` when your condition is true:

```
return {condition && <Option1Radios />};
```

Here is an article about it: https://medium.com/geekculture/stop-using-for-conditional-rendering-in-react-a0f7b96200f8. ps: I still prefer && syntax specially in TypeScript where you can ensure the variable is always a boolean.

Comment: james182 does this answer your question?